# Is there any way to vertically center this td inside its tr tag?

Tags: html, css, datatable

I'm trying to center my `td` with class `.away-flag-container` inside of its `tr` container but I can't figure it out how.

This is my tables code:

```
<div className="table-container">
  <table>
      <thead>
          <tr className="table-header">
              <th>Date/Time</th>
              <th>Stadium</th>
              <th className="hometeam-row">Home Team</th>
              <th></th>
              <th>Away Team</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {data.map((match, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
              <td>{formatDate(match.matchDate)}</td>
              <td>{match.stadium}</td>
              <span className="home-flag-container">
                  <td className="td-bold">{match.homeTeam}</td>
                  <td>
                      <img src={match.homeTeamFlag} alt="Home Team Flag" width="53" height="37"/>
                  </td>
              </span>
              { match.matchPlayed ?  (
                  <td className="td-bold score-row"> {match.homeTeamScore} : {match.awayTeamScore} </td>
              ) : (
                  <td className="td-bold score-row">- : -</td>
              )}
              <span className="away-flag-container">
                  <td>
                      <img src={match.awayTeamFlag} alt="Away Team Flag" width="53" height="37"/>
                  </td>
                  <td className="td-bold">{match.awayTeam}</td>
              </span>
          </tr>
      ))}
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And this is my css styles:

```css
/* TABLE */

.table-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 90%;
  color: #4B5C68;
  border-color: #E4EDF2;
}

.table-header{
  text-align: left;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #E4EDF2;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #F6F7F7;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E4EDF2;
  height: 70px;
}

td {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.td-bold{
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.hometeam-row{
  text-align: right;
}

.score-row{
  text-align: center;
}

.home-flag-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: end;
}

.away-flag-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
}
```

As shown in the image below, my `td` with class `.home-flag-container` centers vertically just fine, but when I try to center my `td` with class `.away-flag-container` it just won't center.

I've tried setting a padding and margin for the class `.away-flag-container` but it also pushes my `td` with class `.home-flag-container`. chat-gpt also suggested to add `height: 100%;` to `.away-flag-container` class but it just didn't work.

Any idea how can I center this `td` vertically without affecting my other tds?

**UPDATE 1**:
I have edited my table code removing the `span` elements but the error remains

```
<td className="home-flag-container td-bold">
                        {match.homeTeam}
                        <img className="img__padding" src={match.homeTeamFlag} alt="Home Team Flag" width="53" height="37"/>
                    </td>

<td className="td-bold away-flag-container">
                        <img className="img__padding" src={match.awayTeamFlag} alt="Away Team Flag" width="53" height="37"/>
                        {match.awayTeam}
                    </td>
```

[image]

Comment: Only TD and TH can be children of TR, you can't have a span as a child of TR.

Comment: @imvain2 in base of what you commented I removed the `span` tags, but I keep getting the same result. Here are my changes:

`<td className="td-bold away-flag-container">
      <img className="img__padding" src={match.awayTeamFlag} alt="Away Team 
            Flag" width="53" height="37"/>

           {match.awayTeam}
 </td>`

Comment: You can't vertically center a table cell within a table row. You can align the cell's _contents_, using the `vertical-align` property.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks, I just created new `tds` and quited trying to nest multiple elements inside `tds`. Then I userd `vertical-align` property and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I just created new `tds` and quited trying to nest multiple elements inside `tds`. Then I userd `vertical-align` property and it worked.

```
<tbody>
            {data.map((match, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                    <td className="r-sm">{formatDate(match.matchDate)}</td>
                    <td className="r-md">{match.stadium}</td>
                    <td className="row-home-team td-bold">
                        {match.homeTeam}
                    </td>
                    <td className="row-home__width">
                        <img src={match.homeTeamFlag} alt="Home Team Flag" width="53" height="37"/>
                    </td>
                    { match.matchPlayed ?  (
                        <td className="td-bold score-column"> {match.homeTeamScore} : {match.awayTeamScore} </td>
                    ) : (
                        <td className="td-bold score-column">- : -</td>
                    )}
                    <td className="row-away__width">
                        <img className="img__padding" src={match.awayTeamFlag} alt="Away Team Flag" width="53" height="37"/>
                    </td>
                    <td className="row-away-team td-bold">
                        {match.awayTeam}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            ))}
            </tbody>
```